# Calling Z3 as black box from Ocaml

Tags: ocaml, z3, formal-verification, first-order-logic, satisfiability

I would like to get access to the quantifier elimination tactic of Z3 in Ocaml, in order to avoiding implementing all the validity and quantifier elimination methods I need.

To do so, I would like to know how to call a Z3 API (for instance, Z3 from Python as a black box) from Ocaml.

Can anyone help?

PS: Would this activity be called multi-paradigm programming? I ask this in order to find more info about similar issues in the future.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

z3 already comes with OCaml bindings:

- API: https://z3prover.github.io/api/html/ml/Z3.html
- Example: https://github.com/Z3Prover/z3/tree/master/examples/ml

If the API exposed isn't enough to do what you want, you should really ask them to expose it through the OCaml API. I think going through OCaml-Python-Z3 would be really problematic as you'd have to juggle both layers.

Comment: My problem with that API is that it does not have a quantifier elimination tactic, does it?

Comment: Sure.. Use https://z3prover.github.io/api/html/ml/Z3.Tactic.html. Then, `mk_tactic ctx "qe"` or similar.

Comment: I will see what can I do, but that definitively answers the question!

Comment: There are many example calls to `mk_tactic` in https://github.com/Z3Prover/z3/blob/master/examples/ml/ml_example.ml

Comment: Yep, but no one uses "qe" and I never see examples of it for Ocaml.

Comment: I've never tried it myself, but I don't see why it wouldn't work. If you put `(help-tactic)` in a file named `t.smt2` and run `z3 t.smt2` it'll print all available tactics. In theory, all the printed tactics should be usable via `mk_tactic`.